# How do i make non paid booking intent using transaction api?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-home, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

i am making a non paid booking intent in my google action using transaction api.

i made table booking intent in dialogflow which ask users 3 questions
1) for how many guests?
2)for which time?
3)for what date?
so basically i want to make this intent using transaction api(google's transaction api)

Note:-this intent is non paid i don't ask users to book table with money but when i give this action for review in google it gets rejected because it needs to be implemented using transaction api.

I want the booking intent to be implemented using transaction api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation clearly states:

> Note: As of May 7th, 2018 we've removed docs for transactions without
>   payment. We don't recommend using this functionality because the
>   existing UX doesn't have capabilities to effectively communicate the
>   details of unpaid reservations to the user. However, existing Actions
>   that perform no-payment transactions may continue to do so.

So it doesn't make sense that they would reject it saying it should use transactions if you're not charging the user. Do you mind sharing the email as it is. Maybe there's something you're missing.

Comment: they rejected my action they said i need to implement transaction api even its a non payment booking system. any idea why? my email is desaijigar01@gmail.com

Comment: I meant sharing the rejection email, not your email address. I think you might be missing some details. Copy-paste the entire rejection please.

Comment: this is what is in email. Thank you for choosing Actions on Google.
Your app allows transactional bookings or reservations. Please note that any app completing transactions (paid or non-paid) must use the Transactions API.
For more information about transactions policy, please visit this page:
https://developers.google.com/actions/policies/general-policies#transactions

Comment: I know you said that this Action is non-paid, but do you clearly state how much the service which the user books via your Action costs during the conversation? (The user will pay when they come, but you still state the full price) This may be the reason why they consider it as a transaction. However, I'd still contact the support team for a more detailed explanation on this matter.

Comment: i dont state any kind of price in conversation basically my google action only asks for table reservation information nothing else and the information which users says(i.e booking time, no of guests ) stores in database. i dont mention the table booking price in conversation.

Comment: Then I'd encourage you to contact the support team and ask them for clarification. Quote the part I referenced from the docs while doing so.

Comment: After contacting support team still i got same reason here's what they said "Your Action allows the users to book a table without implementing Transactions API. Such functionality is considered a physical service that needs to implement Transactions API even there is no financial involve. Please refer to the appropriate link for more information on Transactions API and its policy."

Comment: I see you have asked the same question before and someone said change the term booking to reservation. Have you tried that?

Comment: I'm sorry, then you have no other choice then implementing the Transaction API. Seems like there's something we're missing here. Just start implementing and if you do have specific questions about it, ask in a separate question.

Comment: can i have your email?

Comment: Of course you can: tolunyuksel@gmail.com But please note that I won't be able to help you unless you have a specific question. You can still reach out to me, though.

Comment: Check Your Email Please And Thank You.